# How to debug in currently active integrated terminal in VS Code?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug a Python file in Visual Studio Code using an already active integrated terminal. When I run the debugger, it opens a new terminal and debugs from there. I want to run the debugger in the *currently active* terminal since it's already running an interactive session on a specific machine (via SSH). My `launch.json` file looks like this:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Python: Current File",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${file}",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
    }
  ]
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can not achieve this currently. Why not just connect in the Python Debug Console?

Comment: Thank you. I want to debug using a specific execute node because it has more compute than the default central node. But the Python Debug Console always connects to the central node, and I don't know how to change it. When I try to run ```python /home/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.7.94776/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/launcher 39115 -- main.py``` from the execute node, I get the error ```ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refuse``` even though that's the command being run in the Python Debug Console

Comment: You can attach to a pid and also specify a host/port if you want. use `request: "attach"`, I haven't thoroughly tested, but you can do something like `"processId": "${command:pickProcess}"` if you don't know the pid. It's not immediately clear to me what you are trying to do I just know you can't specify which integrated terminal to use (unless an extension or otherwise provides a workspace setting)

Comment: Got it, thank you. When I choose a process ID I get the error ```Timed out waiting for debug server to connect.``` I assume VS Code can't do what I want but I'll try to be more specific in case it does. I use a shared cluster, where I request interactive jobs on specific machines via srun. When I'm on an interactive job the terminal prompt is ```{name}@{specific_node}```, where I have access to the desired compute. When I debug, I would like all operations to be performed on this node. But when I start debugging with F5 I'm back at ```{name}@{central_node}```, which doesn't have the compute.